# Is admin the least required Permission Role to start SQL Always On Instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql, alwayson

We've got an SQL 2019 Enterprise with Always On. Everthing works fine, but the user, which is starting both instances has admin rights. So I want to change this, but all tutorials are talking about admin rights.

Can I use a Service Account, or a "normal" Domain User with no admin rights? If no, must the user be a Domain Admin or should it have admin rights only on Sql Servers?